# responsive layout issues div layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have three divs that I am trying to align evenly vertically on the page as the height is adjusted. One aligned at the top, one in the middle and one at the bottom. As I adjust the page the bottom one is always at bottom and top at top while the middle div stays in the middle with even amount of space between them all and so they all stay visible. Do I need to use media querys? here is my attempt so far.

```
<body>
    <div id="pageWrapper">
         <div id="top"></div>
         <div id="middle"></div>
         <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>
#pageWrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#top {
    width:200px;
    height:200px
}
#middle {
    margin-top:50%;
    width:200px;
    height:200px
}
#bottom {
    width:200px;
    height:200px
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong approach. If you really need this, I'd suggest using `display: table` and `display: table-row`. Don't forget to set `height: 100%` for `html` and `body` tags to spread the whole page. Then you set `display: table` for the `#pageWrapper` and `display: table-row` for each of your divs.

Here's an [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vCL6G/1/) how it works. Try to resize the box to see it in action.

And here's the CSS:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#pageWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#top, #middle, #bottom {
    display: table-row;
}
#top {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#middle {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto; /* height will adjust automatically */
}
#bottom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: and if I wanted to vertically align the middle divs content centered would I use vertical-align:middle?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But you can put another div in your `#middle` div, e.g. `#middleInner` and add this style to it: `vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;`. See it in my updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vCL6G/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If supporting older browsers isn't a big concern, you could use [css's calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/4LbRu/1/)**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#pageWrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#top {
    width:200px;
    height:calc(100% / 3 - 10px);
    background: red;
}
#middle {
    width:200px;
    height:calc(100% / 3 - 10px);
    background: blue;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#bottom {
    width:200px;
    height:calc(100% / 3 - 10px);
    background: green;
}
p {
    position:relative;
    top:calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

If you need to support older browsers and you don't mind a [Rube Goldberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) approach you could use jQuery:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/4LbRu/2/)**

```
var rubeGoldberg = function () {
    $('#top, #middle, #bottom').height($('body').height() / 3 - $('body').height() * 0.02);
    $('#middle').css({
        marginTop: $(document).height() * 0.03,
        marginBottom: $(document).height() * 0.03
    });
    $('p').each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            top: $(this).parent().height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2
        });
    });
};

$(function () {
    rubeGoldberg();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    rubeGoldberg();
});
```

Or if jQuery isn't really your flavor, here's roughly the same Rube Goldberg approach is [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/4LbRu/4/)**

```
function rubeGoldberge() {
    var secElems = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');
    var mid = document.getElementById('middle');
    var paraElems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < secElems.length; i++) {
        secElems[i].style.height = window.innerHeight / 3 - window.innerHeight * 0.02 + 'px';
        mid.style.margin = window.innerHeight * 0.03 + 'px 0px';
        paraElems[i].style.top = (paraElems[i].parentNode.clientHeight / 2) - paraElems[i].clientHeight / 2 + 'px';
    }

    mid.style.margin = window.innerHeight * 0.03 + 'px 0px';
}

window.onload = rubeGoldberge();
window.addEventListener('resize', rubeGoldberge);
```